# Excel formula Search with Aggregate search results

Tags: excel-formula

I have a formula which is almost working.

```
=IF(Search(".com",C2)C2,ISNA(Left(C2,Aggregate(15,6,Search{(".","_","-")},C2),1)-1),"#N/A"))
```

the first part (search) works well, but regardless of what's in the cell (other than a .com) it throws a #Value error

Comment: You are missing a `,` between `Search(".com",C2) ` and the next `C2`, I assume a typo when transposing to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(".com",C2)),C2,
  IFERROR(LEFT(C2,AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH({".","_","-"},C2),1)-1),"#N/A"))
```

Also consider replacing `"#N/A"` with `NA()` to generate an actual error rather than a text that only *looks* like an error.

Comment: Works great! The NA() just places that value in the cell. Is that an actual error?